# Does anyone understand the sorting rules for this document?

Tags: sorting, rest

I did not understand the document below.

**First，sort the strings that require to be signed according to the parameter names（first compare the first letter of all parameter names and sort them based on alphabetical order; in case that the first letter of more than one parameters is the same, sort these parameters based on the second letter of their names according to alphabetical order, and so on).**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ozWL.png)

The above document tells us to sort, but we didn't use sort in the example.
An example is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8x9y.png)

(
If the above image and description are not enough, I would appreciate it if you read the readme on github.)
(https://github.com/Hotbit-Korea/HOTBIT-KOREA-API-DOCS)
Below is the documentation for the rules for the REST API.
(https://github.com/Hotbit-Korea/HOTBIT-KOREA-API-DOCS/blob/master/rest_api.md#orderput_limit)

With the above example, did I understand what other sort I should use when the parameter name is balance.query and order.put_limit ?

The example is set as a string that is a mixture of strings and numbers.
For example: C88F04701D3349D0A93A0164DC5A4CD9

Comment: It's requesting that you sort the parameters by lexicographical order. I'm only on lunch break so that's all I can contribute now.

Comment: Sir, can you explain even a simple string with an example?
For example: 3AF25CD
string and
There are different parameter names for balance.query and order.put_limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation you linked](https://github.com/Hotbit-Korea/HOTBIT-KOREA-API-DOCS#parameter-signature-) explains the process, but as it seems to have confused you, I'll try rewording it. As you haven't specified a language, I'm going to use JavaScript for the code examples.

First, let's pick an endpoint, such as [`order.pending`](https://github.com/Hotbit-Korea/HOTBIT-KOREA-API-DOCS/blob/master/rest_api.md#orderpending).

This endpoint takes the following parameters (excluding the signature): `api_key` (string), `market` (string), `offset` (32bit Integer), `limit` (32bit Integer).

Let's say I wanted to make a request to this endpoint for the first 100 pending orders on the "ETH/BTC" market, I would need these parameters:

```js
const params = {
  market: "ETH/BTC",
  offset: 0,
  limit: 100
}
```

As the request also requires our API key as `api_key`, we'll add that in too:

```js
// elsewhere:
// const HOTBIT_API_KEY = "5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec";

params.api_key = HOTBIT_API_KEY;
// params.api_key = "5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec"
```

To get this `params` object as a string that the server understands, we can use the `URLSearchParams` class:

```js
const paramString = (new URLSearchParams(params)).toString();
// paramString = "market=ETH%2FBTC&offset=0&limit=100&api_key=5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec"
```

As the request must contain an MD5 signature as `sign`, we must take our string of parameters, append our `secret_key` to it and then calculate its md5 hash:

```js
// elsewhere:
// const HOTBIT_SIGNING_SECRET = "de8063ea6e99bc967ba6395d06fabf50";

const signature = md5(paramString + "&secret_key=" + HOTBIT_SIGNING_SECRET);
// signature = "2156c177bf5373b67d0f86771f6f6581"
```

Next we need to add the uppercased signature to our query parameters:

```js
params.sign = signature.toUpperCase();
// params.sign = "2156C177BF5373B67D0F86771F6F6581"
```

Then make our request:

```js
fetch("https://api.hotbit.co.kr/api/v2/order.pending", {
  method: "POST",
  body: (new URLSearchParams(params)).toString(),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
})
  .then((response) => { /* do something */ })
  .catch((error) => { /* handle error */ });
```

But wait! We got back an "invalid signature" error with our request! What went wrong? This is because we didn't sort the parameters the same way the server did and we calculated different signatures.

In our request, we calculated the signature using the following parameter string:

```js
"market=ETH%2FBTC&offset=0&limit=100&api_key=5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec"
```

Here, the parameters were given in the order: `market`, `offset`, `limit`, `api-key`

The server expected the (alphabetical) order: `api-key`, `limit`, `market`, `offset`

At least in JavaScript, we can correct this mistake by following these steps:

1. Collect our parameters into an object called `params`:

```js
const params = {
  market: "ETH/BTC",
  offset: 0,
  limit: 100
  api_key: HOTBIT_API_KEY
}
```

2. Convert our `params` object into an array of name-value pairs:

```js
const paramPairs = Object.entries(params);
// paramPairs = [
//   ["market", "ETH/BTC"],
//   ["offset", 0],
//   ["limit", 100]
//   ["api_key", "5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec"],
// ]
```

3. Sort the pairs array by each parameter's name, alphabetically:

```js
paramPairs.sort(([nameA], [nameB]) => String(nameA).localeCompare(nameB))
// paramPairs = [
//   ["api_key", "5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec"],
//   ["limit", 100]
//   ["market", "ETH/BTC"],
//   ["offset", 0],
// ]
```

4. Convert the pairs to a parameter string (using `URLSearchParams` again):

```js
const paramString = (new URLSearchParams(paramPairs)).toString();
// paramString = "api_key=5eae7322-6f92-873a-e9bc214fd61517ec&limit=100&market=ETH%2FBTC&offset=0"
```

5. Combine it with our secret and calculate the signature:

```js
const signature = md5(paramString + "&secret_key=" + HOTBIT_SIGNING_SECRET);
// signature = "63d87ee1ef3094b0e34d71ec8d512d83"
```

5. Add the uppercased signature to our parameters:

```js
params.sign = signature.toUpperCase();
// params.sign = "63D87EE1EF3094B0E34D71EC8D512D83"
```

6. Make our request:

```js
fetch("https://api.hotbit.co.kr/api/v2/order.pending", {
  method: "POST",
  body: (new URLSearchParams(params)).toString(),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
})
  .then((response) => { /* do something */ })
  .catch((error) => { /* handle error */ });
```

Now we don't get the invalid signature error!

In your language of choice, I recommend building some functions you can reuse for this:

```js
function getSignedParameterString(params) {
  const pairs = Object.entries(params)
    .sort(([nameA], [nameB]) => String(nameA).localeCompare(nameB));
  const paramString = (new URLSearchParams(pairs)).toString;
  const signature = md5(paramString + "&secret_key=" + HOTBIT_SIGNING_SECRET)
    .toUpperCase();
  return paramString + "&sign=" + signature;
}

function makeHotbitPOSTRequest(endpoint, params) {
  return fetch(`https://api.hotbit.co.kr/api/v2/${endpoint}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: getSignedParameterString(params),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Edit:** As this API seems to ignore the standards of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, you'll need to swap out using `URLSearchParams` for this function:

```js
function getHotbitParamString(params) {
  if (!params || typeof params !== "object") {
    throw new TypeError("params must be a truthy object");
  }

  const paramsArray = Array.isArray(params)
    ? params
    : Object.entries(params);

  return paramsArray.map(([name, value]) => 
    Array.isArray(value)
      ? `${name}=${JSON.stringify(value)}`
      : `${name}=${value}`
  );
}
```

Then you'll change this code:

```js
(new URLSearchParams(params)).toString()
```

to

```js
getHotbitParamString(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sincere reply. exactly solved it.
However, there was a problem that the string generated by the URLSearchParams method could not be recognized (ETH/BTC => ETH%2FBTC) among the strings that should be included in the body of the Hotbit API service. Everything else was really the best answer.

Comment: @김대현 Even though their docs say to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type, it seems they are ignoring the standards of that content type and that is a bug on their end.